# Computer turns off sponaneously. Is it the PSU?

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure, crash

My computer turned off multiple times spontaneously. It happens instantly and it also instantly starts rebooting. I didn't do anything with high ressource usage (just a browser open and powerpoint) before and since the computer reboots instantly and everything works fine I'm assuming that it has nothing to do with overheating. I think the PSU is just too old/broken. How can I make sure it's the PSU (without having it measured)? Do you have other assumptions on what it could be? Please let me know if you need any additional information. 
[image]

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power" Guid="{331c3b3a-2005-44c2-ac5e-77220c37d6b4}" />
    <EventID>41</EventID>
    <Version>6</Version>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Task>63</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8000400000000002</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-05-08T09:03:54.646991700Z" />
    <EventRecordID>16322</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="4" ThreadID="8" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>Oliver-PC</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="BugcheckCode">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter1">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter2">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter3">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckParameter4">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="SleepInProgress">0</Data>
    <Data Name="PowerButtonTimestamp">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BootAppStatus">0</Data>
    <Data Name="Checkpoint">0</Data>
    <Data Name="ConnectedStandbyInProgress">false</Data>
    <Data Name="SystemSleepTransitionsToOn">0</Data>
    <Data Name="CsEntryScenarioInstanceId">0</Data>
    <Data Name="BugcheckInfoFromEFI">false</Data>
    <Data Name="CheckpointStatus">0</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Go look into the eventlog and see if there is a bugcheck. It will say if the previous fail is unexpected and what the reason is. If there is a memory dump, you experienced a BSoD, but it happened so fast, that you did not see the blue screen itself. This indicates its not the PSU. If there is only the shutdown, but no memory dump, then it is the PSU.

Comment: I would try to boot some [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/) LiveUSB stick and see if the same failure appears. If yes, it is probably hardware related.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well, it's not like the error appears every 5 minutes. More like every couple of days. Don't wanna be on an Ubuntu LiveUSB untill the error appears eventually...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Computer turns off sponaneously. Is it the PSU?

Its possible it is, and it is possible it isn't.

You need to access the eventlog and search for the events about the unexpected shutdown. There will be multiple events. One for the shutdown itself and one after the shutdown stating that the previous shutdown was unexpected.

If you experienced a very fast BSoD, then the eventlog will also have a log entry about the BSoD with EventID 1001. If you indeed find this, you can rule out the PSU in most cases. The BSoD will tell you what happened and why it shutdown. These events also come with a STOP code and usually a memory dump that can be inspected. Googling the STOP Code will allow you to find out what is happening. At this point it can still be both a hardware or software problem, but windows detected a problem and halted the OS to prevent further damage.

If you don't find this log entry, then you get the same result as instantly turning the computer off without proper shutdown, which could be the PSU failing, or any other electrical problem, such as a very quick loss of power that the PSU could not recover from. If the last it the case, you often will see some lights go out for a brief moment, depending on what type of light you have. LED lights will stay on for example, as they need a capacitor to be driven.

So at that point it can be the PSU, especially if it happens more frequently. But if its just one, it could be something completely outside of the PC too.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the window's event viewer. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Double click the entry to read its report to and search for other event log entries related to the same shutdown to get the bigger picture. Not all useful entries are critical or errors. Some useful entries can actually be information entries. Just try to get a general sense of what happened from 15 minutes before the shutdown to 2 minutes after the crash.

Comment: Well before the crash there is three times this error: "svchost (7576,R,98) TILEREPOSITORYS-1-5-18: Fehler -1023 (0xfffffc01) beim Öffnen von Protokolldatei C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database\EDB.log" But I have no idea what that is supposed to tellme. Then after the crash they just tell me that the system has been shut down unexpectedly and that "surveilance events" (translated from german by me) have been deleted from transport.

Comment: Look for any event that says BUGCHECK. If you don't find them, near the crash, that means there was no BSoD.

Comment: Should be EventID 1001: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bsod-event-1001-bugcheck/4f7d93f2-6092-4987-a6d3-2911e30d19fa

Comment: There is no bug check or anything like that. I do have event ID 1101, however, but no 1001. so that means there was no bsod and that means that there was an electric problem of some kind right?!

Comment: Yes. If there's no bug check, aka no BSoD, the system lost power in an unusual way, that could not be caught by the OS itself, which is usually an electrical problem of some sort, including but not limited to a faulty PSU. Be sure to check all occurences though, not just the last one. Maybe the last one did not have a BSoD, but other instances may.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Can you please put the information on how to recognize a BSoD event log (bug check/Id 1001) in the answer? Then I will except it.

Comment: @Max made the changes. :)